# I want to do filter type and date for line check table and former table. Can I filter two tables if there is no date data in the former table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to create a filter that filters date and former type. But the problem is that there is no date's data in the former table. Is it possible to do this filter?  This is my table, code and output that I want:

Table former

| Type | formerID |
| --- | --- |
| SMG | SMG6017SK |

Table line check

| Date | Month | formerID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-17 | 2022-02 | SMG6017SK |

Code:

```
$Type= $_POST['Type'];
$Date = $_POST['Date'];
                                    

if(!empty($Type) && !empty($Date)) {
                                     
    SELECT * 
    FROM `line_check` 
    WHERE line_check.Date = $Date 
    INNER JOIN former ON former.formerID = line_check.formerID 
    WHERE former.Type = $Type
```

OUTPUT:

| Date | Type | Former ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17-02-2022 | SMG | SMG6017SK |

Comment: Move your  INNER JOIN before your WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Move your INNER JOIN before your WHERE. Also make sure to use *parameterized queries* instead of using variables in your SQL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM line_check 
INNER JOIN former ON former.formerID = line_check.formerID
WHERE line_check.Date = ?
AND former.Type = ?
```

Comment: I just could not figure out how I could get it work in a parameterized way. Could you please help me ?

Comment: Are you using `mysqli` or `PDO`? Take a look here for examples for both mysqli and PDO, https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-vs-mysqli#fetching. I can help if you get stuck.